# my kitten is litter trained but does a poo on his bed and blankets

Tags: toilet-training, cat-litter

I recently got my kitten, the owner says he is litter trained, yet he hasn’t used the litter box and has only done a poo on his bed and a blanket. I am using a different ,scented, litter to what he had in his home and I’m not sure if that is the problem

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Because this is not a forum but a question and answer site, youbwill get better answers as specific your question is. Guessing is not good behavior here. So maybe you can edit your question and add an aim you want to reach, or a specific thing you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

A kitten in a new home is scared and confused. He may not be comfortable enough yet to leave his bed and go wandering around, plus he may have trouble finding your litter box (and getting into it) in time anyway. So, he poops where he knows it’s safe.

Also, you should be using the *exact* same litter (and food) as his prior home until he’s fully settled in. Cats recognize things mostly by smell, and he may not realize that your scented litter *is* litter yet.

So, switch to the litter he knows and move the box closer to where he sleeps. Once he is using it regularly, you can consider *slowly* switching to your preferred brand and location.

Comment: "he may have trouble finding your litter box" This is why more current recommendations for adopting cats and kittens includes the advice to place the cat in the litterbox when first bringing him into the new home. Wherever he goes to hide for the first day or two, he'll know how he got there from the litterbox and be able to find his way back.